# Как устранить данную проблему "Заблокирована попытка создания WebMediaPlayer"

Tags: javascript, html

заметил такую ошибку на сайте.

У меня стоить звук клика при нажатию, звук работает все хорошо. Но спустя какое то время клика. Выдает данную ошибку и звук перестает работать. Данная ошибка появляется спустя примерно 500-1000 кликов.

Ошибка

```
[Intervention] Blocked attempt to create a WebMediaPlayer as there are too many WebMediaPlayers already in existence. See crbug.com/1144736#c27
```

Код

```
<div id="big-btn" onclick="clicksound()" class="poiner">
   <div draggable="false" class="pointer__img"></div>
</div>

function clicksound(){
    var audio = document.createElement('audio');
    audio.setAttribute("autoplay","true");
    audio.innerHTML = "<source src=\"/sound/clickmenu.mp3\" type=\"audio/mpeg\">";
    document.body.appendChild(audio);
}
```

Comment: Если перевести текст ошибки, а именно **there are too many WebMediaPlayers already in existence**, то станет ясна суть проблемы: Вы при каждом клике добавляете в body новый `<source src=\"/sound/clickmenu.mp3\" type=\"audio/mpeg\">`, а старые не удаляете. В какой-то момент их становится слишком много, и браузеру надоедает это терпеть.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, понял в чем была моя ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил данную проблему изменив код на вот этот.

```
function clicksound(){
    var audio = document.createElement('audio');
    audio.src = '/sound/clickmenu.mp3'
    audio.autoplay = true;
    return true;
}
```